# use quizzer from learnr package without `runtime: shiny_prerendered`

Tags: r, r-markdown

This is originally posted in [Rstudio-Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/learnr-package-quizzer-without-runtime-shiny-prerendered/54406) but didn't get any reply. So here I am.

I am trying to do a quizzer with a Rmarkdown, which renders a simple self-contained HTML.

What I can see with the functions `learnr::question()` and `learnr::answer()` we already mentioning the correct answer. So it should be able to work around getting rendering correct answer upon chosen on client-side (in HTML) without communicating with server (in this case shiny).

My question is it really necessary to run a shiny server for that, if yes is there an alternative javascript-based R-package address this issue.

Comment: From [this](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/index.html#shiny_components): The learnr package uses runtime: shiny_prerendered to turn regular R Markdown documents into live tutorials. Since tutorials are Shiny applications at their core, it’s also possible to add other forms of interactivity using Shiny (e.g. for teaching a statistical concept interactively).

Comment: Not 100% sure what the question is here. What is the issue you are running into specifically? Are the correct answers not rendering because you are publishing to an environment without the server side? You shouldn't have to "run a shiny server for that", I think it would be helpful if you could clarify the issue you are running into. If you aren't running into an issue yet and are asking before trying it and you hope it works a certain way, I would try to actually do it and deal with issues as they come up. More details around where you are deploying your tutorial could also help.

Comment: @Ricky I have tried and then only came up here. It is not working without a server site.  It's less of an issue more of I am trying out to explore ideas around it. If people have come across a similar issues.

Comment: Could you clarify what "without a server site" means? If that doesn't work can you use shinyapps.io? I believe they have a free tier and that wouldn't have whatever issue you seem to be encountering